# Adding node to MAAS

Tags: maas

Scenario:

1) I have MAAS Sever 1.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 (MAAS Server)

2) I have another server on same network which already has Ubuntu 14.04 installed. ( MAAS Client)

3) I configured MAAS Servert to not unmanaged cluster

4) I added manually mac address of MAAS client as a new node, and it went to commissioning state

5) But it  remain at that mode how can I force my client to start commissioning process

any idea?

Thanks

6) Thanks "Vembu" I tried the solution suggested by "Vembu " here is the result:

Case 1: `maas maas nodes accept-all`

Thanks  but after running this command I got:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
<br>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
 <br> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maascli/__main__.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
<br>  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maascli/__init__.py", line 46, in main
    options.execute(options)
 <br> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maascli/api.py", line 189, in __call__
    insecure=insecure)
 <br> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maascli/api.py", line 66, in http_request
    return http.request(url, method, body=body, headers=headers)
  <br>File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1569, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  <br>File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1316, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  <br>File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1251, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  <br>File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 900, in connect
    self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port) + sa[2:])
  <br>File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/socks.py", line 424, in connect
    self.__negotiatehttp(destpair[0], destpair[1])
  <br>File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/socks.py", line 390, in __negotiatehttp
    raise HTTPError((statuscode, statusline[2]))
httplib2.socks.HTTPError: (403, 'Forbidden')
```

Case 2: `sudo maas maas nodes accept-all`

it returns `[ ]`
and still in commissioning!

Answer (score 1):

You can accept and commission all nodes from the commandline. This requires that you first log in with the **API key**,

https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/maascli.html#api-key

```
$ maas maas nodes accept-all
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I just do an "Add Node" in the MAAS console to prep for an enlistment.  In this way I can just use the DNS name I want and set the Wake On LAN option.  You do need to know in advance the MAC address of the Ethernet adapter in question, however.

Then when the node does its PXE boot it will just enlist faster without all the back-and-forth of you approving it and another boot.